Idempotent algebras over absolutely flat ring
Is it possible to classify all idempotent algebras over an absolutely flat ring? Are there any idempotent $E_{\infty}$ algebras which are not discrete?
I am particularly interested in the special case of Boolean rings.
Edit: All rings are assumed commutative.

I think that Maxime's argument works for non-commutative rings as well (a map $A\to B$ of associative rings is called idempotent if the base change functor on perfect modules is a homological epimorphism).

Makes sense. But for commutative ones I am hoping it's possible to classify idempotents from Spec k, but idk how to think of the noncommutative absolutely flat rings geometrically. Also not sure if it's too much to hope for all absolutely flat rings--I don't really understand even the Boolean case.

They must all be discrete.
Let $k$ be absolutely flat - for any $k$-modules $M,N$, we have $\pi_*(M\otimes_k N)= \pi_*(M)\otimes_k \pi_*(N)$. Now if $A$ is idempotent over $k$, let us examine what this says about $\pi_0$: $\pi_0(A)\cong \pi_0(A\otimes_k A) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=0}\pi_p(A)\otimes_k \pi_q(A)$ which contains, as a summand, $\pi_0(A)\otimes_k\pi_0(A)$ which, in turn, maps surjectively onto $\pi_0(A)$, so that not only are the other terms $0$, also $\pi_0(A)\otimes_k \pi_0(A)\cong \pi_0(A)$, so $\pi_0(A)$ is a classical idempotent - in particular also an absolutely flat ring.
Let's now look at $\pi_n(A) \cong \pi_n(A\otimes_k A)\cong \bigoplus_{p+q=n}\pi_p(A)\otimes_k\pi_q(A)$ - this also contains $\pi_n(A)\otimes_k\pi_0(A)\oplus\pi_0(A)\otimes_k\pi_n(A)$ as a summand if $n\neq 0$, but both maps are also surjective onto $\pi_n(A)$, which forces them to be $0$, and so $A$ is discrete.

Thanks Maxime! Can you elaborate a little on the calculation of $\pi_*(M \otimes_k N)$? Sorry I don't immediately see this

If every module is flat, the Tor spectral sequence degenerates.

Thanks I guess this means at least for Boolean algebras the idempotent algebras are just (co?)-idempotent profinite sets over the profinite set of the Boolean algebra? I'm assuming that for a absolutely flat algebra to be Boolean you just need all residue fields to be $\mathbb{F}_2$.

So for Boolean algebras it seems like there is a 1-1 correspondence between idempotents and compact subsets?
